# Conversion of a data into time series object

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have a file and I want to perform time series analysis on the data.Unfortunately I am unable to convert data into time series object?

Here is the snapshot of the code:

[I have two column timestamp and closing price.I have tried various code but still unable to do so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQInR.png)

```r
INTC <- read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/INTC-data.csv")[,c(2,6)]

head(INTC)

tail(INTC)

new_data<-xts(INTC)
```

> Error:"Error in xts(INTC) : order.by requires an appropriate time-based object"

Comment: Please take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Posting screenshots of RStudio containing code is... well... not a great reproducible example. Especially take a look at how to show sample data.

Comment: At this point: Perhaps the error *is* obvious: Since RStudio didn't find the function `as.xts.data.frame`, I'm asking myself if you loaded `library(xts)`.

Comment: Good find, @MartinGal, that shows how much I notice in pics-of-code/data. Thanks for having the patience to find that.

Comment: @r2evans Your comment made me take a closer look at the screenshot... I usally ignore those. But the question is actually about another error (which I noticed now...). Obviously I need to sleep.

Comment: Read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag.  Note that it asks for easily reproducible test data, not images which require that those responding retype the data.

Answer (score 1):

The question's use of the `xts` function is incorrect but it doesn't really matter since xts cannot represent that sort of data in the first place. xts requires an index class that represents dates or date/times such as `Date` or `POSIXct` but here we have plain numbers.  Create a zoo series instead.

```
library(zoo)

# test data
INTC <- data.frame(ts = 930:935, close = 18.55)

z <- read.zoo(INTC); z
##   930   931   932   933   934   935 
## 18.55 18.55 18.55 18.55 18.55 18.55
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The ts column has time from 9.30 am  to 4.00 pm for date between 19-June-06 to 30-June-06.How to convert ts(column) into time series object?

Comment: I cant be sure without more test data but perhaps: `library(xts); dates <- as.Date("2006-06-19") + cumsum(INTC$ts == 930) - 1;
datetime <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s %04d", dates, INTC$ts), "%Y-%m-%d %H%M", tz = "");
xts(INTC$close, datetime)`